# Jquery pagination problem

Tags: jquery, pagination

Hello i have this grid working fine here:
http://tourscript.com/jqueryasp/default2.asp
i start adding a pagination to this using the "nettut paginate anything tutorial" so it become like this:
tourscript.com/jqueryasp/default.asp
My problem is that when i click the pager to navigate in another page the Edit function fires up for some reason and i don't know how to fix this .

Thank you

Comment: Don't seems to work that well : when ordering by age several times, the order is no good.

Comment: thanks that was because somebody added letters instead of numbers for age .. now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'TBODY TR' as a selector in the paginate call will be matching on your hidden editing rows as well.

Try creating a selector that would not match those editable rows.

For example,

```
 $(".tablesorter").paginate({ limit: 3, content: 'TBODY TR.dataline' });
```

Comment: Fiona you may want to checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309269/litlle-jquery-problem-when-integrate-the-pager still there's a problem with the grid... thanks